# How do you take baked textures and apply them to a Blender Render/ Game Engine Object

Tags: game-engine, baking

After baking the materials & textures into a .png file and applying that .png file to a blender render, of the EXACT same shape that they were baked from, I have found a weird result. It doesn't apply over the object in the same way that it was baked off the object. It winds up like below.
[image]

Comment: You probably baked to a different set of uvs.

Answer (score 1):

After reading more about baking, and playing with it some, I found that my error was trying to bake the materials and textures from my cycles render to an image, and then putting that image on a blender render.

To take materials and textures from a cycles render to a blender render or game engine, first you must bake them and apply them over the object in the same file in cycles render. Then you can change to blender render or game engine and go to nodes. Create a new materials node and connect the normal and vector slots between the nodes.